# append a related Model in Phalcon

Tags: php, model, relational-database, phalcon

I wrote a vcard class with Phalcon in PHP. The vCard Model is initialized like this.

```
// Inside the BS_VCard class
public function initialize(){
    $this->hasMany("id","BS_VCardElement","vCardId",array(
        "alias" => "elements",
        'foreignKey' => array(
            'action' => Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Relation::ACTION_CASCADE
        )
    ));
}
```

Its elements are initialized like this

```
// Inside the BS_VCardElement class
public function initialize(){
    $this->belongsTo("vCardId","BS_VCard","id",array("alias" => "vCard"));
    ...
}
```

If a user reads a vCard and adds another element, it doesn't work as expected. To simplify the use I added some fascade methods like this

```
public function addDateOfBirth($date){
    $element = new BS_VCardElement();
    $element->setName("BDAY");
    $element->addValue($date);
    // This doesn't work
    $this->elements[] = $element;
}
```

The [Docs/Storing related records](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#storing-related-records) do not explain how to append fresh data like this to the related table.

I also tried this

```
$this->elements[] = array_merge($this->elements,array($element));
```

But the save method seems to ignore the added element. Save() returns true.

Comment: Hmm I'm not 100% sure but have you tried assigning VCard to VCardElement first? `$element->vCard = $this`?

Comment: nice try, but didn't work. By the way I ran into the problem that when the related elements are actually not possible to write, the save will return true anyway. Makes it harder to debug.

Comment: For some reason reading the `$this->elements` before adding the array as written in the [Docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#storing-related-records) will end in an unwritten set of elements. Something else I didn't know was that existsing relations will not be overwritten when adding an array with child elements to the magic `$this->elements`

Comment: Hi. Did you find the answer for this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked a couple of months ago but since I ran into a similar issue I decided to share my results anyway.

And here's what I found. Lower case aliases ('elements') don't seem to work whereas upper case aliases ('Elements') do.

To add one element you can do this;

```
$this->Elements = $element;
```

To add multiple elements you can do this;

```
$elements = array($element1, $element2);
$this->Elements = $elements;
```

After that you have to save the vcard before accessing the elements again. If you don't, phalcon will just return a result set with only the elements already in the database. (Not sure if this can be changed somehow.)

And here's the documentation (where all this is not mentioned): http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#storing-related-records

Comment: I don't know. I also posted it on the phalcon forum but no one replied yet.

Comment: i think they don't accept bugs without a testcase showing it is a real bug.

Comment: I did not report a bug but asked if that was the expected behaviour in the forum. I hope someone will reply soon.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Phalcon source code](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/resultset.zep), the Resultset object is immutible.

```
/**
 * Resultsets cannot be changed. It has only been implemented to 
 * meet the definition of the ArrayAccess interface
 *
 * @param int index
 * @param \Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface value
 */
public function offsetSet(var index, var value)
{
    throw new Exception("Cursor is an immutable ArrayAccess object");
}
```

It appears that replacing the element with an array is the only way to implement an "append" or modification of the resultset (other than delete which IS supported).

Of course this breaks the [`\Phalcon\Mvc\Model::_preSaveRelatedRecords()`](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model.zep) because the function ignores the class properties and refetches the related from the Model Manager (and resets the `model::$element` attribute at the end).

I feel frustrated by this because appending objects to a collection seems like a very common task and not having a clear method in which to add new items to a parent seems like a design flaw.

Comment: This question is related to a phalcon version way before the source code you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think related elements might have some magic functionality invoked when you set the properties, so simply using $this->elements[] (evidently) doesn't work.  Perhaps try re-setting the entire variable:

```php
public function addDateOfBirth($date){
    $element = new BS_VCardElement();
    $element->setName("BDAY");
    $element->addValue($date);

    $elements = $this->elements;
    $elements[] = $element;
    $this->elements = $elements;
}
```